# How do I get the version fo an OSGi component from within itself?

Tags: java, osgi, version

I'd like to print the version of the OSGi bundle.

```
class Production {
  public Production() {
    System.out.println("Version:" + OSGI.getMyVersion());
  }
}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: By OSGi component, you mean an OSGi bundle? Do you have a variable that holds the bundleContext or the bundle that you are in?

Comment: How do I get a Bundle Context?

Comment: In that case the questions are: How do you start your tests? What testing framework do you use? (BNDTools based, PAX Exam, simple JUnit, ...)

Comment: I'm not going to do it during testing. This is for production code. I'll update the example to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the reference to the bundle and its version with this API:

```
org.osgi.framework.FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass()).getVersion()
```

Comment: While that works I would rather avoid using FrameworkUtil if there is a nicer way to access the BundleContext. For example it will make your code hard to test as it is difficult to mock a static class like FrameworkUtil.

Comment: Why would you need to mock a part of a framework? I personally do trust whatever one has in org.osgi.* packages.

Comment: @ChristianSchneider ...and introducing a BundleActivator only when you need access to the bundle (context) itself seems like overhead for me. And Blueprint is much more overhead.

Comment: You need to mock all OSGi APIs to do unit tests that run outside the OSGi framework. You should always have a set of such tests inside each bundle project as they run much faster than integration tests. Of course if possible then structure you code in a way that you can test your code independently of the OSGi APIs. This is not always possible though.

Comment: Having said that there are sure cases where FrameworkUtil is the simplest solution. Just be aware of the downsides.

Comment: @IlyaShinkarenko, well if you don't use Blueprint or an activator how do you make sure your bundle is started and therefore the code is actually running? If you use DS, you're back to the better solution to actual use the bundle context, as this is know to the bundle and doesn't require an extra FrameworkUtil.

Comment: @AchimNierbeck FrameworkUtil.getBundle() will return you the bundle anyway, it does not have to be started. If the bundle is not started, the BundleContext will be null, but it is not needed in this context.

Comment: @IlyaShinkarenko, if the bundle isn't starte it's not needed, but we run into a philosophical question right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
BundleContext.getBundle().getVersion()
```

The way you access BundleContext depends on the technology you use inside your bundle. If you use the basic OSGi APIs then implement a BundleActivator to access the BundleContext. If you use an injection framework like Blueprint you can normally inject the BundleContext into any property.